# URL mapping not triggering controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am following along in the book Spring in Action trying to build the Spittr application. I created my configuration classes and home controller, but when I call localhost:8080/ I get a 404.

---

Project

[image]

---

SpittrWebAppInitializer.java

```
package com.hamerm.spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

---

WebConfig.java

```
package com.hamerm.spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.hamerm.spittr.web.controllers")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

---

RootConfig.java

```
package com.hamerm.spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.hamerm.spittr", 
    excludeFilters=@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class))
public class RootConfig {

}
```

---

HomeController.java

```
package com.hamerm.spittr.web.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {

        return "home";
    }

}
```

---

web.xml 
(I removed the config that eclipse put in here by default when making a new Spring Web MVC projectbecause it was complaining about multiple context listeners)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


</web-app>
```

---

I have tried navigating to `http://localhost:8080/Spittr/`, `http://localhost:8080/`, and `http://localhost:8080`. All result in a 404. No exceptions show up in the Java console though, so it's like its not even registering the request.

---

This is a part of what the console prints when I run my application

```
INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
Sep 21, 2016 2:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 21 14:21:43 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.hamerm.spittr.config.RootConfig]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2062 ms
Sep 21, 2016 2:21:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 21 14:21:45 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.hamerm.spittr.config.WebConfig]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hamerm.spittr.web.controllers.HomeController.home()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 21 14:21:45 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1649 ms
Sep 21, 2016 2:21:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 21, 2016 2:21:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 21, 2016 2:21:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9745 ms
```

---

What do I need to do to get my application running? Thanks!

Comment: if localhost:8080 gives you 404, my guess is that there is something wrong with the server

Comment: did you try different endpoints as well? for instance: [login](http://localhost:8080/login) or [registration](http://localhost:8080/registration) ? Have a look into the `HomeController` there are some more. I just cloned the repository, set up the project in my ide and it works as expected.

Comment: @DanielBubenheim I haven't gotten that far into development yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't post my pom.xml because I didn't think it was relevant. Apparently it was.

The culprit that was this line
`<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>`

Made the resulting war file have that version appended to the name, which meant it had to be at the end of the url I use to access the application.

The solution was to add this to the `<build>` section of pom.xml

`<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>`

now the resulting war was simply named `spittr.war` and I was able to access the application at `localhost:8080/spittr`

Answer (score -1):

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hamerm.spittr.web.controllers.HomeController.home()
```

This indicates the entry has been registered and it should be triggered.

There is one another method where a welcome file can be triggered using below.
Add this to your WebConfig which adds `home.jsp` as your welcome file.

```
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
  }
```

If this works, then try with other endpoints as suggested, so that gives the base to access to application.